# Macro to loop through variables and store results SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following variables: `A_Bldg B_Bldg C_Bldg D_Bldg`. I want to multiply them by `INTSF` and store the result in a new variable, `Sale_i`. For example, `A_Bldg * INTSF = Sale_A`, `B_Bldg * INTSF = Sale_B`, and so on.

My code is:

```
%macro loopit(mylist);
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&mylist));
%do J = 1 %to &n;
%let i = %scan(&mylist,&J);

  data test;
  set data;
  sale_&i. = &i._Bldg * INTSF;
  run;

%end;
%mend;

%let list = A B C D;
%loopit(&list);
```

This only produces `Sale_D`, which is the last letter in the list. How do I get `Sales A-C` to appear? The first four lines of code are so I can loop through the text A-D. I thought about doing it with arrays, but didn't know how to choose the variables based on the A-D indicators. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently looping through your list and recreating the `test` dataset every time, so it only appears to have `sale_d` because you're only viewing the last iteration.

You can clean up your loop by scanning through your list in one data step to solve your problem:

```
%let list = A B C D;

%macro loopit;

    data test;
        set data;
            %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list.));
            %let this_letter = %scan(&list., &i.);
                sale_&this_letter. = &this_letter._Bldg * INTSF;
            %end;
    run;

%mend loopit;

%loopit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `%DO` loop is in the wrong place. But really you do not need to use macro code to do something that the native SAS code can already do.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  array in A_Bldg B_Bldg C_Bldg D_Bldg ;
  array out sale_1-sale4 ;
  do i=1 to dim(in);
    out(i)=intsf*in(i);
  end;
run;
```